# java - slf4j with logback not showing logs

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I've slf4j with logback which works perfectly fine on my local machine.
But when I deploy the jar on the server, I don't see any logs.

Not able to figure out the issue. Any help / pointers would be helpful!
Things I've done

1. I've `ConsoleAppender` configured which works perfectly fine on my local.
2. I've tried logging to a file with `RollingFileAppender`, works fine locally
3. I've checked the permission of the `logfile` in the server and my App has permission.

Few things I looked at
1. If there are multiple `logback.xml` will it cause any issue.

Thanks!

Comment: please post the contents of your pom.xml and output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. You can also make sure if your logback.xml file is actually getting bundled in jar or not. you can extract jar using `jar -svf jar-file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with sentry dependency `raven-logback`. These were the dependencies in my `build.gradle`

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.21'
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
compile 'com.getsentry.raven:raven-logback:7.7.0'
```

Switched to `log4j` and got it fixed.

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'
compile 'com.getsentry.raven:raven-log4j:7.7.0'
```